# Delete From multiple tables based on GPA and ID

Tags: mysql

I don't See Why this wouldn't work I have been trying to figure it out. I an trying to delete students from an enrollment table and student table where there GPA is less than 0.5.

```
    DELETE e, s FROM Enrollemnt e JOIN  Student s ON s.StudentID = e.StudentID
WHERE s.GPA < 0.5 
AND s.StudentID = e.StudentID;
```

Comment: About 4100 queries in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate `s.StudentID = e.StudentID` is redundant in the `WHERE` clause; that same predicate is already expressed in the `ON` clause. (I would think that's acceptable to the optimizer; just a bit confusing to the human reader, why that would be expressed twice.)

Apart from that oddity, the statement should "work". One possible issue would be foreign key constraints; the order the rows are deleted from the tables may cause foreign key constraints to be violated.

I suspect the problem is the spelling of the `Enrollment` table, looks like the table name is misspelled, and the error would be something on the order of "unknown table".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I came up with....

```
DELETE Enrollment, Student FROM Enrollment INNER JOIN Student 
WHERE Enrollment.StudentID=Student.StudentID
AND Student.GPA < 0.5;
```

Comment: Hello you asked the question and you answered yourself . Is it valid ?

Comment: Please tell us why did it work and while using Alias like `e,s` the query did not work ?

Comment: I ran and deleted 4181 rows. I just played with it til I got it.

Comment: So, the problem was actually the *spelling* of the `Enrollment` table. Nothing to do with removing the table aliases.

Comment: @drhunn , :) dont use Copy Paste . You misspelled as told by spencer :) Its `Enrollment` Not `Enrollmnt`

Comment: I just rewrote it and it worked. I have been at this since 10 am and about to head home thank you for letting me know.